# How to send emails without outgoing port 25 with Plesk and postfix?

Tags: linux, email, port, postfix, plesk

I have a VPS server running Plesk with postfix and my IP is blocking outgoing port 25. Do you know how to set up my server to send emails from it? Can't some other ports be used for this?

I managed to enable other ports for incoming emails. According to various guides, I should change the `/etc/postfix/main.cf` file.

Comment: Welcome to [Super User](https://superuser.com/ "https://superuser.com/"). Please see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask "https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask") then edit your question.   Pay particular attention to the section titled [Search, and research](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask:~:text=Search%2C%20and%20research)

Comment: Plesk can fairly heavily modify the linux on which it runs. Can you give us your plesk version and os with version please? It might also be worth tagging the question with postfix. The other standard ports for mail are 587 and 465, but you'll need to modify both main.cf and master.cf to get the services and security lined up correctly.

Comment: Which ISP is blocking the ports – your home, or the VPS host?